# Archive manipulating using qt framework

Tags: qt, archive

Is it possible to handle different type of archive (zip,rar,7z,tar,) using qt framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: [How to compress data with Qt? | Qt Developer Network](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_to_compress_data_with_qt)